# Solving Congruence Equations \Bbb Z_11

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have an equation $$ 6 \pmod {11} x = 3 \pmod{11} $$

and I need to find the variable x which solve the equation.
I found that $ x=6 $ by trying $x=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Before, posing this question, I made a search here and in youtube and found the way which described above: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9Eo6Bsvm4M.

That`s an easy equation but the question is how can I find the variable without try all the options?